# django many to many queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

i have two models :

1-----

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True , upload_to='profile' )
    profession = models.ManyToManyField(Profession)
```

2-----

```
class Profession(models.Model):
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

i want to display all the profession that i have
and in the same time i want to display the number of accounts that they have this profession

like this pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG2rI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate per profession name like this:

```py
Profession.objects.values('profession').annotate(num_accounts=Count('account'))
```

Which will give you an output like:

```
<ProfessionQuerySet [{'profession': 'SomeProfessionA', 'num_accounts': 22}, {'profession': 'SomeProfessionB', 'num_accounts': 20}, ...>
```

Comment: oooooooooo broo thank you sooooooooooooo much 
but how did you know this ??? it's work like i want